# React redux component not updating on store change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I came across this problem where my one component doesn't update itself on store change.

This is the component that doesn't work `Single.js`:

```
export default class Single extends React.Component {

componentWillMount(){
    const { items } = this.props.articles;
    const { id } = this.props.params;

    if ( items.length == 0 || typeof items == 'undefined' ) {
        console.log('fetching');
        this.props.fetchArticles(fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/article').then(res=>res.json()));
    } 

}

render(){
    const { items } = this.props.articles;
    const { id } = this.props.params; 

    var index;

    for(var i in items){
        var item = items[i];
         if (id == item.id){
                index = i;
                break;
         }
    }

    var item = this.props.articles.items[index];

    console.log(this.props.articles.items);

    return <h1> {item.title} </h1>
}

}
```

This is my `ArticleList.js` component which does work and updates itself properly:

```
    import React from "react";

    import Vote from '../ArticleParts/Vote';
    import Thumbnail from '../ArticleParts/Thumbnail';
    import Title from '../ArticleParts/Title';

    export default class ArticleList extends React.Component {

        componentWillMount(){
            this.props.fetchArticles(fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/article').then(res=>res.json()))
        }

        renderArticles(item, i){
            return(
                <div class="row" style={{marginTop: "10px"}} key={i}>
                    <Vote id={item.id} score={item.score} i={i} {...this.props}/>
                    <Thumbnail thumbnail={item.thumbnail} id={item.id} type={item.type}/>
                    <Title title={item.title} id ={item.id}/>
                </div>
            );
        }
        render(){

            console.log(this.props.articles.items);

            return(
                <div>
                    {this.props.articles.items.map(this.renderArticles.bind(this))}
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

I use connect in `App.js`:

```
    import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
    import {connect} from 'react-redux';
    import * as ActionCreators from '../actions/ActionCreators';

    import Main from './Main';

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      return {
        articles: state.articles,
        votes: state.votes
      }
    }

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
      return bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch);
    }

    const App = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);

    export default App;
```

And this is my index for the router:

```
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={history}>
                <Route path="/" component={App}>
                    <IndexRoute component={ArticleList}></IndexRoute>
                    <Route path="/:id" component={Single}></Route>
                </Route>
            </Router>
        </Provider>,
        app
    );
```

EDIT========

This is my reducer `articles.js`:

```
    import * as ActionConst from '../actions/ActionConst';

    const initialState = {
        fetching: false,
        fetched: false,
        items: [],
        error: null
    }

    function articles(state=initialState, action){
        switch (action.type){
            case ActionConst.articles_req: {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    fetching: true
                }
            }
            case ActionConst.articles_got: {    
                return {
                    ...state,
                    fetching: false,
                    fetched: true,
                    items: action.payload
                }
            }
            case ActionConst.articles_err: {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    fetching: false,
                    fetched: false,
                    error: action.payload
                }
            }
            default: 
                return state;
        }
    }

    export default articles;
```

This is my store.js:

```
    import {createStore, compose, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
    import {syncHistoryWithStore} from 'react-router-redux';
    import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';
    import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
    import logger from 'redux-logger';
    import promise from 'redux-promise-middleware';


    import RootReducer from './reducers/index';

    import votes from './data/votes';
    import articles from './data/articles';

    const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, logger());

    const store = createStore(RootReducer, middleware);

    export const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)

    export default store;
```

In my `ActionCreators.js`

```
export function fetchArticles(data){
  return {
    type: action.articles_const,
    payload: data
  }
}
```

Sorry there is a lot of code. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: There's not enough code. The reducer(s) may be helpful and also the shape of JSON that the fetch grabs from the server. Also, "doesn't update itself" is too vague. Does it display article(s)/items/unclear things but then not update when those change? Or does it never display anything? And what does that `console.log` log?

Comment: I've included the reducer, and the structure of JSON is in the initialState in my reducer. So for my `ArticleList.js` component that works, it would display blank, then a list of articles. But in my `Single.js` it just displays blank, but it should be displaying its title for now. That `console.log` just simply prints out `[]`. This is what my console looks like: http://i.imgur.com/Gg9Byrv.png

Comment: Do you want the component to be updated after articles are fetched? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr that's exactly what I want. It works for my `ArticleList` component, but I just don't understand why it doesn't work for my `Single` component

Comment: Where is `fetchArticles` defined?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr In my `ActionCreators.js` an action that returns type and payload

Comment: @Parkicism Can you provide it's code?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr There u go

Answer (score 0):

I guess this code:

```
componentWillMount(){
  this.props.fetchArticles(fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/article').then(res=>res.json()))
}
```

Should be:

```
componentWillMount(){
  fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/article').then((res)=>{ 
    this.props.fetchArticles(res.json());
 })
}
```

Comment: Make a `console.log(res)` just before `this.props.fetchArticles(res.json());`. What is logged out?

Comment: `console.log(res)` prints out this: http://i.imgur.com/teA0XwU.png. While `console.log(res.json())` prints out http://i.imgur.com/6yTY9Cm.png

Comment: Also If I replace my code in my `ArticleList.js` with your code, it doesn't work anymore and it logs this http://i.imgur.com/1qNSwXV.png

Answer (score 0):

`resp.json()` also returns a promise. So you will have to call another `then` to get the data:

Change:

```
this.props.fetchArticles(fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/article').then(res=>res.json()))
```

to

```
this.props.fetchArticles(fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/article').then(res=>res.json()).then( data => data))
```

Or more cleanly:

```
const { fetchArticles } = this.props;
const data = fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/article')
    .then( res => res.json() )
    .then( data => data )
    .catch( err => throw err /* handle error somehow */ );

fetchArticles(data);
```